# Миро и мирра

Tags: орфография

В разных источниках я вижу разное написание названия этого масла. Есть, например, выражение "одним миром мазаны". То есть, использована формы "миро". 
Но часто я встречаю вариант "мирра", относящийся к тому же маслу.
А как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мирра и миро — два самостоятельных слова с тесно связанным происхождением и пересекающимся смыслом. Мирра — это ароматная **смола**, получаемая из растения, никогда не догадаетесь, "мирра", по названию которой стали называть любые благовонные вещества. В их числе и "миро" — ароматное **масло** на основе елея, приготовленное особым способом и освящённое.

Оба слова восходят к одному, разделились ещё в греческом языке. К слову, сегодня "миро" — это "Μύρο", а мирра — либо тоже "Μύρο", либо "Μύρρο". В русском языке раньше писалось "мирр**о**".

Вывод. Если речь идёт о священном масле, то правильно только "миро".

Comment: >Есть, например, выражение "одним миром мазаны". 

А что это означает? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Nikolja, на первых порах значило "одной веры" (вещество миро использовалось в церковных обрядах), затем стало значить то же, что и "одного поля ягоды", то есть люди с общими привычками, взглядами и пр., чаще всего отрицательного плана.

Answer (score 0):

> В разных источниках я вижу разное
> написание названия этого масла...
> "миро"...  "мирра".

***МИРРА*** -- смола;  входит в состав ***ЕЛЕЯ***, на основе которого делается ***МИРО***. См.:

> ***смирна***
>
> см’ирна (Исх.30:23 ; Пс.44:9 ;
> Прит.7:17 ; Мат.2:11 ; Мар.15:23 ;
> Иоан.19:39 ) — сильно благоухающая
> смола миррового дерева, растущего в
> Аравии и Эфиопии. **Называется также
> *мирра*. Является составной частью священного *миро*.** Была одним из
> даров волхвов родившемуся Иисусу
> (Мат.2:11 ), что символизировало, как
> полагают, признание в Нем Истинного
> Человека. (см. ароматы)
>
> ***Библия. Ветхий и Новый заветы. Синоидальный перевод. Библейская
> энциклопедия.. арх. Никифор. 1891.***

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/biblerus/71701/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0

> ...выражение "одним миром мазаны".

См. http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/1541/%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%9C_%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%9C_%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%97%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%AB

Comment: >>ИРРА -- смола; входит в состав ЕЛЕЯ, на основе которого делается МИРО. 

@slava1947, елей — это оливковое масло, в его состав, разумеется, мирра не входит. Миро делается на основе именно елея, а мирро — составляющая дополнительная и необязательная.

Comment: Пересвет: "елей — это оливковое масло, в его состав, разумеется, мирра не входит."=== Может, не входит, а может -- и входит… См. статью ЕЛЕЙ здесь:
http://slavdict.narod.ru/_0172.htm

Comment: slava1947, насколько я понимаю, в этом словаре под *елеем* понимается само *миро*, то есть цепочка *мирра* > *елей* > *миро* неверна. Либо елей — это оливковое масло, на основе **которого** делается миро, либо елей — само составное вещество, **которое** делается в том числе с применением мирры.